# XmlSlurper in Groovy Script --- Insert nodes to GpathResult using external closures

Tags: groovy, closures, gpath

I have a problem with the below scenario:

-- I have a GPathResult "body" to which  I want to append some more xml (nodes and children)
-- Some parts are common so I am trying to have them kept in an outer closure "commonNode" I can insert wherever I need

```
// some more code here to get body

def commonNode = {
return {
  node2() {
     child("childValue")
   }
 }
}

body.appendNode(
 {
   node1("value1")
   commonNode()
   node3("value3")
 }
)
```

What I want to get after I would call XmlUtil.serialize(body) is this:

```
...
 <body>
  <node1>value</node1>
  <node2>
   <child>childValue</child>
  </node2>
  <node3>value3</node3>
 <body>
...
```

however  structure is missing from the result entirely, so I guess there is something wrong with the way I call the outer closure "commonNode()".

Hope someone has an answer. Let me know if you need further details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
import groovy.xml.*

def xml = '<body/>'

def body = new XmlSlurper().parseText( xml )

def commonNode = { 
    node2 {
        child "childValue"
    }
}

body.appendNode { 
    node1 "value1"
    commonNode.delegate = delegate
    commonNode()
    node3 "value3"
}

println XmlUtil.serialize( body )
```

Comment: Prompt and useful answer. I just have one additional curiosity: Is there a functional difference between my syntax and yours: child("childvalue") compared to child "childValue"?

Comment: @Shinoko no, it's the same thing :-)  Parentheses in this situation are optional :-)

Comment: Is it possible to have a parameter as well? In example the value of child node ("childValue") to be sent as a string when  calling the closure. What code changes are required?