# Grails: Add XML node as last web.xml node in plugin's doWithWebDescriptor

Tags: xml, grails, nodes, web.xml

I have the following code in my plugin's definition file:

```
def doWithWebDescriptor = { xml ->
  // Implement additions to web.xml (optional), this event occurs before
  xml.'welcome-file-list'[0] + {
    'security-constraint'({
      'web-resource-collection'({
        'web-resource-name'('Java Melody Monitoring')
        'url-pattern'('/monitoring')
      })
      'auth-constraint'({
        'role-name'('melody')
      })
    })

    'login-config'({
      'auth-method'('BASIC')
      'realm-name'('Restricted Area')
    })
  }
}
```

This adds "security-constraint" and "login-config" nodes to the web.xml file, however, I currently have it hard-coded to be added after the "welcome-file-list" node.  What I can't figure out is how to simply tell it to add these nodes as the last nodes in the "web-app" root node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grab children, append after last child.

```
xml.children()[-1] + {
    'security-constraint'({
      'web-resource-collection'({
        'web-resource-name'('Java Melody Monitoring')
        'url-pattern'('/monitoring')
      })
      'auth-constraint'({
        'role-name'('melody')
      })
    })

    'login-config'({
      'auth-method'('BASIC')
      'realm-name'('Restricted Area')
    })
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

While dmahapatro's answer will work, I believe that [appendNode](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/slurpersupport/GPathResult.html#appendNode%28java.lang.Object%29) is the clearest way to go about it.

Something like this would work:

```
xml.appendNode {
    'security-constraint'({       
        'web-resource-collection'({         
            'web-resource-name'('Java Melody Monitoring')         
            'url-pattern'('/monitoring')       
        })       
        'auth-constraint'({         
            'role-name'('melody')       
        })     
    })      
    'login-config'({       
        'auth-method'('BASIC')       
        'realm-name'('Restricted Area')     
    })
}
```

Comment: Can you please also add the link where `appendNode` takes a closure as a parameter?

Comment: A `Closure` is not an `Object`?

Comment: This accepted answer uses similar syntax: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19026002/xmlslurper-in-groovy-script-insert-nodes-to-gpathresult-using-external-closu

Comment: Does it work with the above implementation? Yes, Closure is an object. :)

Comment: I tested the exact code I posted on the Groovy Web Console, so I'm going to say it works.

Comment: Correct. I was looking at [Node](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/util/Node.html) definition and it does not work that way if XmlParser is used because XmlParser returns a node. I am not sure whether above implementation would work depending on the implementation in `doWithWebDescritor`. `xml` is an Element and it returns a NodeList for children. Will test it in a plugin though.

Comment: As per this: http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/plugins.html#hookingIntoRuntimeConfiguration, `doWithWebDescriptor` comes with a `GPathResult` as the first argument. I tested with a `GPathResult` and it worked.

Comment: You are correct. *A plugin can provide a doWithWebDescriptor property that is assigned a block of code that gets passed the web.xml as an XmlSlurper GPathResult.* - from docs. XmlParser would be different.

Comment: Unfortunately using this appendNode method results in a "org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified." error.  Using my original hard coded way doesn't produce this exception.  Also using dmahapatro's children() method works too.

Comment: @HarryMuscle make sure you don't have `+` after `appendNode`.

Comment: @dmahapatro I double checked and I do not have a + sign when trying the appendNode method.

Comment: Reason I think is because the actual class for `xml` is [`DeferredElementNSImpl`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/apiDocs/org/apache/xerces/dom/DeferredElementNSImpl.html) which inherits Node from Xerces API. Will look into it as well.

Comment: I also get the "INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR" error under Grails 2.3.9 and webxml 1.4.1 plugin.  @dmahapatro 's answer works for me.